# signInWithPopup method not working firebase react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am try to authenticate with google signin in firebase with react and redux. But the problem is when the popup window opens then it shows not able to reach page. I am using firebase v9.

Here is my firebase config file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithRedirect
} from "firebase/auth";

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

initializeApp(config);

const auth = getAuth();
const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const facebookAuthProvider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

export {
  auth,
  googleAuthProvider,
  facebookAuthProvider,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithRedirect
};
```

Here below is the google signin trigger reducer

```
export const googleSignInitiate = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(googleSignInStart());
    signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider)
      .then(({ user }) => {
        dispatch(googleSignInSuccess(user));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(googleSignInFail(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Here below is the error popup window

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Facing the same issue.. Can you try signInWithRedirect so that you can see what is happening to the network call?

In mine, there is a handler?api which is not resolving

Comment: Ok I will check it and let you know

Comment: @JayaramKasi Now my code is working perfectly. I think the problem is with firebase server. Have you checked your code?

Comment: Now mine is also working. weird